# Write log to execution folder if specified folder is inaccessible

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I would like to write the log to the `.exe` path if the specified `value` of the `file` is an inaccessible directory.

E.g. if the program runs from `C:\prog\` and the `<file>` value is `E:\logs`, if `E:\` is not mapped, I want the log to be in `C:\prog\', I did search but couldn't find anything yet (found some dynamic runtime solutions but no static one).

This is my current config:

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"
        value="E:\Logs\mylog_%date{yyyyMMdd_hh-mm}.txt" />
  <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd.lo\g" />
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
  <!-->lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" /-->
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that, in order to write to the `Program Files` folder - or any other "restricted" folder - your application requires administrative privileges.

Comment: You can't do that in config, it would have to be code.